# Alternative term for "fire and forget"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I recall reading an instruction manual to an old FPS (first person shooter) game years back, and it noted a [particularly destructive cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFG_(weapon)) being the "ultimate in fire and forget weaponry", since it essentially destroys everything in a large room, sometimes including the player wielding this portable cannon.

**Is there a more accurate term than "fire and forget" though?** The general use of this term seems to revolve around the ability of the user to open a door, blast the weapon, and close the door before the splash (area of effect) damage destroys the wielder along with everything else in the room.

While technically accurate, it's to my understanding that "fire and forget" describes the ability of a projectile to automatically track its target, such as guided missiles; rather than the ability of the user to use it and not concern themselves with the result since aiming isn't a concern.

Comment: Great question! I didn't really know of this phrase but it sounds very useful.

Comment: See also: [Is the term “fire and forget” well understood?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/29429/50044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ***[launch and leave](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Launch+and+leave)***? Rig it and run?

As with many idioms, this one thrives on its use of alliteration. If you're looking for a better tagline, try to come up with one yourself and see if it sticks. You could always go back to the old Ronco line, "set it and forget it."

Comment: There is always the old term [*blunderbuss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunderbuss), which was used to mean an inaccurate but effective weapon.